# Vertical align of elements needs 10px more for Chrome

Tags: fonts, cross-browser, height, css

I'm experimenting a weird issue by using the font Luckiest Guy.

I have some buttons, a elements with width and height, and for align the text vertically, I'm using the same height and line-height. That works, it's a css trick, but I need 10px more of line-height to align the text vertically in Chrome, FireFox and Safari!!

Works in Chrome/FF/Safari

```
.btn {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 40px // need 10 px more to be vertically aligned!
}
```

Works in IE9+

```
.btn {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px // normally aligned
}
```

Anybody knows why can that be? Has anybody experimented anything similar? Any workaround or solution for it?

Thnx a lot

Comment: have you tried removing default browser's styles?

Comment: What happens if you use line-height: 1;? Are the line heights still different sizes? Have you tried it with different fonts and it works correctly? My suggestion is to use padding-top (as line-height is known to display differently in different browsers if it is set in px), but it really depends on your needs.

Comment: Everything commented has been used. I think that the only answer to this is the use of that special font 'Luckiest Guy', because any other normal font works like it should. The only solution has been to use a different stylesheet for IE9 and a hack for IE10+. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been to use a stylesheet for IE9 using a normal combination of line-height and height, a hack for IE10+:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {}
```

and use 10px line-height more for the rest of browsers.

The use of the 'Luckiest Guy' font renders that way in modern browsers.

Comment: Realized now that the problem exists only when using Mac Os! The 10 extra pixels are not needed when using windows, nevermind which browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
box-sizing: content-box;
```

should fix it in chrome.

```
.btn::-moz-focus-inner { margin-top: -5px; }
```

should fix it in firefox (setting the appropriate margin).

Standards seem particularly bad with forms, so it is an area where using the default styles can often be sensible in order to get them looking decent in all browsers without too many hacks.

One other thing to consider is using a reset (or a normalise) style sheet - these try and make all browsers behave the same and can help with lots of frustrations like this.  Here's a popular one that works with your problem: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: We are already using normalize.css, and it's not fixing it. Thanks for your answer.